# css flex 2x2 grid full screen with centered images view crop

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a very simple markup of 4 images, where the goal is to get a 2x2 responsive image grid that will:

- Maintain 2x2 fit screen on all screens regardless of size, using only flex.
- Keep the images centered and maintain aspect ratio( "cropping" them from
  view if needed according to screen )
- Be able to transform on hover.
- Not change the markup ( and don't ask why )
- Try to achieve a situation where a single property ( or min number of ) could
  transform the grid to 4 x whatever ( 4 in a row ) meaning not change markup to galley rows of 2..

the markup is :

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="gallery">

          <img class="item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="Example image">
          <img class="item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="Example image">

         <img class="item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="Example image">
          <img class="item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="Example image">



       </div>

   </div>
```

And the css :

```
/** Add basic reset **/
.container {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* justify-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    /* max-height: 100vh; */
    height: 100vh;
}
img {
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 2s;
    flex-basis: 49%;
    max-height: 49vh;
    align-self: center;
    /* max-width: calc(49vh - 10px); */

}
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 49%;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img:hover {
 transform: scale (1.1);
}
```

adding :

```
  img {
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

kind of works, but it has a "hack-ey" feels to it and also have 2 major problems (1) it will indeed "crop" the images - but they are not centered and (2) on hover they will "spill" from container.

I am quit sure that this is NOT the right way to achieve what I need, but not so sure as to what flex-property I am missing, or using wrong here.

***Edit I*** to be more clear attached an image of what I am trying to achieve, where each represents a different size screen / viewport without any scroll.
Images need to be always centered and cropped in edges according to screen ( somewhat like a full-screen background usually works )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may help, although I'm not entirely sure if I fully understand your request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .child {
        /* FOR 4 IN A GRID */
        flex: 1 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%; 
        max-height: 50%;

        /* FOR YOUR 4 IN 1 ROW */
        /* flex: 1 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%; */

        /* FOR BOTH */
        padding: 5px;
        object-fit: none;
    }
    .child:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XYWLSWlOL._SX466_.jpg" class="child">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XYWLSWlOL._SX466_.jpg" class="child">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XYWLSWlOL._SX466_.jpg" class="child">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81XYWLSWlOL._SX466_.jpg" class="child">
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

[Updated Version](https://jsbin.com/guxemuzumi/1/edit?html,output)

It's up to you to to add in media queries to set the size of the container itself.

Comment: thanks for the effort -  but i need the grid to fit the screen as a 2x2 with centered images. a normal grid would be trivial to achieve.  also, there is no need for media-queries because it should be the same for all screens,.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I believe I have what you want now. It checks all 4 of the boxes that you have. I only thought a while ago that you wanted it in the shape of a square so that it would be more of a grid. This one is responsive to screen size. Only that the size of my placeholder image might be too small for some displays.

Comment: yep, that one seems exactly what i intended. I missed the `box-sizing: border-box;` i guess.. thanks ! quick question, is the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` important here ?

Comment: It's important in responsive design. Without this, most browsers tend to scale everything down to fit into the screen, with it, it forces the browser to have an upper limit to start with.